# Firebase functions Promise.catch() handle specific errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

Generalized Question: Handle a specific error when a promise in rejected.

```
// Some firebase task generating a promise
.catch(err => {
// Handle the specific error here.
});
```

Specific error:
If a file exists in storage, it should be updated and if it does not, a new file must be created.

```
admin.storage().bucket().file('path/to/file').download({
    destination: 'temporary/file/path'
}).then(() => {
    // Change the file and upload it.
}).catch(err => {
    // Handle error(create file) if the file does not exist
})
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a basic handle on what you need to accomplish, what's your specific question? I'd recommend taking a look at `err.code` for the error type you need to handle, then just returning a new promise that creates the file.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thanks. The `err.code` worked for me. The code in my case was `404`(file not found error). The specific question was to prevent the creation of a new file in case of any other errors (because that would lead to data loss). So, the `err.code` was the perfect solution for my case.